# Why do I have to include an extension to access its module's methods?

Tags: ruby

I've created a ruby C extension `TestExt`, successfully compiled it, but when I try and use it in irb I can only access it's methods after i've called `include TestExt`.

I'm testing it like this:

```
c:/test>irb -I lib
irb(main):001:0> require 'TestExt'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> TestExt.hello()
NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for TestExt:Module
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0> TestExt.instance_methods
=> [:hello]
irb(main):004:0> include TestExt
=> Object
irb(main):005:0> TestExt.hello()
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> hello()
=> 0
```

Do you always have to `include` an extension? Is there an alternative way of includeing that doesn't make the method `hello` global? Why can I see `hello` in the `TestExt.instance_methods` but not access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say yourself in your question, `hello` is an instance method, ergo you first need to mix your module into something, so that you *have* an instance to call it on.

When you `include` a mixin at the top-level, that is basically equivalent to

```
class Object
  include TestExt
end
```

which mixes `TestExt` into `Object` and thus makes `hello` available as an instance method of the `Object` class. Since *everything* inherits from `Object`, including `Module`, this makes the `hello` instance method available to both your `TestExt` module and the anonymous `main` object (which is what `self` evaluates to at the top-level).

Try `''.hello`, and it will work also, since you mixed `TestExt` into `Object` and `String` inherits from `Object`.

> Do you always have to include an extension?

No.

> Is there an alternative way of includeing that doesn't make the method hello global?

Yes: just don't `include` it in the global scope.

> Why can I see hello in the TestExt.instance_methods but not access it?

Because it's an instance method.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Confusion caused partly by using the wrong function to register the modules methods (I was using `rb_define_method` where I should use `rb_define_module_function`).